# Is it possible to create the low-level grapics API (similar to OpenGL)?

Tags: opengl, assembly, graphics

1. Is that possible to create a low level framework similar to *OpenGL*?
2. What do you need to building such API?

Comment: Very possible, though not something you just do.

Comment: 1. Yes
2. A solid understanding of graphics programming?

Comment: 2: Convince nVidia, ATI, and Intel to implement your API.

Comment: If it isnt possible, how would OpenGL exist? Surely OpenGL counts as similar to OpenGL? This question is way off topic.

Comment: If you are new to programming, what you are suggesting is climbing mt everest in the winter with nothing except shorts and a tshirt

Comment: @mjs It is possible, though very unlikely that you would succeed. Because 1: OpenGL is a huge library and 2: They work together with a lot of graphics card vendors, like Nvidia, ATI, etc. Because they need each of them to implement their API into their graphics cards. Then if someone just comes along creating a new similar API and is created by a single person, they the chances of them implementing is well 0%

Comment: 1. Why Would you want to reinvent the wheel if you are "new to this programming world" 2. Try reading this http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/ and if any of it doesn`t bamboozle you on the first reading then you should be working at NVidia or ATI

Comment: @All:Thanks guys for YES...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, implementing something like OpenGL is not possible. Since the time OpenGL has decended from the heavens complete, writing something like it was forbidden by all common religions.

But really, what you'll actually need is about 21 years of work, a few thousands of developers and broad support from all industry leaders, so yea, piece of cake.

Or actually, all you need is just a notepad and a pencil, writing is easy!

Comment: +1 for the both serious and humorous answer!

Comment: I was about to post something along much the same lines